# I didn't get menu option in wordpress. Where to find it?

Tags: wordpress, menu

I am looking for adding menu item in my site via wordpress. But under the Appearance section and other section , there is no menu option. So, how can I add the menu item dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

In WordPress, menus are theme-dependant. Take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen to see how to use menus in WordPress themes, how themes support menus, and how to add menus to themes.